# How to show different location in Map Views depends on selected Picker? (React Native)

Tags: react-native, geolocation, android-mapview, picker

everyone. I am building a react native app about showing a different location in Map Views depends on selected picker.

I was thinking to used conditional statement by detecting words contain in the string, I use `string-contains` library to detect some words in a string. Here is the example of my code:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
renderMap(){
  if(contains(this.state.name, "Branch 1")){
            return <MapView
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: 53.433980,
              longitude: -2.950960,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
            style={{height: 200, width: 200, padding: 10, flex: 3, justifyContent: 'space-around'}}
          ><MapView.Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
          }}
        /></MapView>;
        } else if(contains(this.state.name, "Branch 2")){
           return <MapView
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: 51.491610,
              longitude: -0.135560,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
            style={{height: 200, width: 200, padding: 10, flex: 3, justifyContent: 'space-around'}}
          ><MapView.Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
          }}
        /></MapView>;
        }
        else if(contains(this.state.name, "Branch 3")){
           return <MapView
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: 53.461220,
              longitude: -2.269540,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
            style={{height: 200, width: 200, padding: 10, flex: 3, justifyContent: 'space-around'}}
          ><MapView.Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
          }}
        /></MapView>;
        }
        else if(contains(this.state.name, "Branch 4")){
           return  <MapView
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: 51.262290,
              longitude: -1.081610,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
            style={{height: 200, width: 200, padding: 10, flex: 3, justifyContent: 'space-around'}}
          ><MapView.Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
          }}
        /></MapView>;
        }
}
render(){
const branchesPicker = this.state.branches.map((item, branch_id)=> {
      return(
            <Picker.Item
            label={item.name}
            value={item.address}
            key={item.branch_id}/>
        )
    });
      this.renderMap();
return(
<View style={styles.container}>
      <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.name}
          mode="dropdown"
          style={{ height: 50, justifyContent: 'center', flex:4, alignItems: 'stretch', }}
          onValueChange={(item)=> this.setState({name: item})}>
        {branchesPicker}
    </Picker>
        {this.renderMap()}
      </View>
```

When I run this code, the picker is working fine but when I tried to change the picker, the map is not changing as I supposed. It's only showing a static one map view (but the map view is not always from branch 1, sometimes it's showing branch 2 or 3 when I reload it. But the point is, it's not changing..)

fyi, `this.state.name` is showing the branch's name of selected picker.

Thank you so much for your help! It really means a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using react-native-maps.

Initial region is used to render and show the location when the map is loaded for the 1st time. When or if you want to change the location after the loading, You can use animateToRegion or many other similar [methods](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods). So when you want to change the location on the map when something is picked in picker, just call these methods with your inputs.

here is it snippet of code for reference.

```
 this.map.animateToRegion({ latitude: region.latitude, longitude: region.longitude, latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta }, timeToChangeRegionInMilliSeconds);
```